# MVC passing variables within a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Not sure if I am following MVC conventions but I have some variables passed from one Controller A to Controller B. My objective is to have another view named 'Publish' with an `ActionLink` to do some processing upon clicking on it.

The redirection from Controller A:

```
var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Publish", new { accTok = facebookAccessTok, fullImgPath = fullpath });
            return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
```

I now have the values for 'accTok' and 'fullImgPath' in my 'Publish' Index for Controller B which contains an ActionLink in its View to do the processing, but I am not sure how do I pass them to my 'Publish' ViewResult' method to do it:

```
namespace SF.Controllers
{
    public class PublishController : Controller
    {

    public ViewResult Index(string accTok, string fullImgPath)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // This ViewResult requires the values 'accTok' and 'fullImgPath'
        public ViewResult Publish()
        {
            // I need the values 'accTok' and 'fullImgPath'
            SomeProcessing();
            return View();
        }

        public SomeProcessing(string accessToken, string fullImagePath)
        {
            //Implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Index View:

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Publish</h2>

    <br/><br/>

    @Html.ActionLink("Save Image", "Publish")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand the full scenario. You have parameters from **action** `Index` and you need them at the action `Publish` on the same controller?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this

```
public ViewResult Publish(string accTok, string fullImgPath)
        {
            SomeProcessing(accTok,fullImgPath);
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would immediately process and display the publish view which isn't what I want. I need the index page to be displayed first and do the SomeProcessing after the ActionLink is clicked.

Comment: I guess my point was that to get access to the accTok and fullImgPath variables you needed to pass them into the Publish method to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
public ViewResult Index(string accTok, string fullImgPath)
{
    ViewModel.Acctok = accTok;
    ViewModel.FullImgPath = fullImgPath;
    return View();
}

public ViewResult Publish(string accTok, string fullImgPath)
{
    SomeProcessing(accTok,fullImgPath);
    return View();
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save Image", "Publish","Publish",new {accTok=ViewModel.Acctok, fullImgPath=ViewModel.FullImgPath},null )
```

Instead of the ActionLink you could also make it a form with hidden input fields (if this method changes thing in a database/on disk, it actually should be in a post).

But anyway use a viewmodel to pass the parameters from the index action to the view, so that in turn can send them to the publish action. This is generally the way to do it with the stateless web in MVC.